# Logon identified -- any backend storage of this number?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-cookies

When you log on to an ASP.NET app you are issued with a logon cookie (I think it's called ASPX_AUTH or similar). What is the structure of this cookie? Does the server actually maintain any logon state, or is it purely what's within the cookie (in which case, can I force a very long logon state by chaning the cookie expiry?)

Tx, AJ.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is hashed and encrypted.
If you modify it, it will become invalid.

This behavior is controlled by the `protection` attribute of the [`<forms >` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) in Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a long logon state, or for the login to not timeout, set two things in forms entry in the web.config:

timeout="_numer_of_minutes"  slidingExpiration="true"

This will keep your user logged in.